# configuring flannel to use a non default interface in kubernetes

Tags: ubuntu, networking, kubernetes, flannel

Is there a way to define in which interface Flannel should be listening? According to [his documentation](https://github.com/coreos/flannel/blob/master/Documentation/troubleshooting.md#vagrant) adding FLANNEL_OPTIONS="--iface=enp0s8" in /etc/sysconfig/flanneld should work, but it isn't.

My master node configuration is running in a xenial(ubuntu 16.04) vagrant:

```
$ sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr 10.244.0.0/16 --apiserver-advertise-address 10.0.0.10 

$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml
clusterrole "flannel" created                                                                    
clusterrolebinding "flannel" created                                                                   
serviceaccount "flannel" created                                                                 
configmap "kube-flannel-cfg" created                                                                                                                                                       
daemonset "kube-flannel-ds" created   


ubuntu@master:~$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/k8s-manifests/kube-flannel-rbac.yml
clusterrole "flannel" configured                                                          
clusterrolebinding "flannel" configured
```

Host ip addresses:

```
$ ip addr                      
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1     
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00                                    
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo            
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever                                               
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host                  
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever                                               
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000                                                                                    
    link/ether 02:63:8e:2c:ef:cd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff                                       
    inet 10.0.2.15/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global enp0s3                                     
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever                                               
    inet6 fe80::63:8eff:fe2c:efcd/64 scope link                                              
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever                                               
3: enp0s8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000                                                                                    
    link/ether 08:00:27:fb:ad:bb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff                                       
    inet 10.0.0.10/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global enp0s8                                     
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever                                               
4: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default                                                                                            
    link/ether 02:42:da:aa:6e:13 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff                                       
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 scope global docker0   
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever                                               
5: flannel.1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default                                                                                         
    link/ether 5e:07:a1:7f:97:53 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff                                       
    inet 10.244.0.0/32 scope global flannel.1 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever                                               
    inet6 fe80::5c07:a1ff:fe7f:9753/64 scope link                                            
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever                                               
6: cni0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000                                                                                     
    link/ether 0a:58:0a:f4:00:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff                                       
    inet 10.244.0.1/24 scope global cni0      
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever                                               
    inet6 fe80::7037:fcff:fe41:b1fb/64 scope link                                            
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Pods names:

```
$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces                                                                                                                                         
NAMESPACE     NAME                             READY     STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE  
kube-system   etcd-master                      1/1       Running             0          2m   
kube-system   kube-apiserver-master            1/1       Running             0          2m   
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-master   1/1       Running             0          2m   
kube-system   kube-dns-545bc4bfd4-gjjth        0/3       ContainerCreating   0          3m   
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-gdz8f            1/1       Running             0          1m   
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-h4fd2            1/1       Running             0          33s  
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-rnlsz            1/1       Running             1          33s  
kube-system   kube-proxy-d4wv9                 1/1       Running             0          33s  
kube-system   kube-proxy-fdkqn                 1/1       Running             0          3m   
kube-system   kube-proxy-kj7tn                 1/1       Running             0          33s  
kube-system   kube-scheduler-master            1/1       Running             0          2m
```

Flannel Logs:

```
$ kubectl logs -n kube-system kube-flannel-ds-gdz8f -c kube-flannel
I1216 12:00:35.817207       1 main.go:474] Determining IP address of default interface
I1216 12:00:35.822082       1 main.go:487] Using interface with name enp0s3 and address 10.0.2.15
I1216 12:00:35.822335       1 main.go:504] Defaulting external address to interface address (10.0.2.15)
I1216 12:00:35.909906       1 kube.go:130] Waiting 10m0s for node controller to sync
I1216 12:00:35.909950       1 kube.go:283] Starting kube subnet manager
I1216 12:00:36.987719       1 kube.go:137] Node controller sync successful
I1216 12:00:37.087300       1 main.go:234] Created subnet manager: Kubernetes Subnet Manager - master
I1216 12:00:37.087433       1 main.go:237] Installing signal handlers
I1216 12:00:37.088836       1 main.go:352] Found network config - Backend type: vxlan
I1216 12:00:37.089018       1 vxlan.go:119] VXLAN config: VNI=1 Port=0 GBP=false DirectRouting=false
I1216 12:00:37.295988       1 main.go:299] Wrote subnet file to /run/flannel/subnet.env
I1216 12:00:37.296025       1 main.go:303] Running backend.
I1216 12:00:37.296048       1 main.go:321] Waiting for all goroutines to exit
I1216 12:00:37.296084       1 vxlan_network.go:56] watching for new subnet leases
```

How do I do to configure flannel in kubernetes **to listen in enp0s8 instead of enp0s3**?

Comment: on centos, I added the 'FLANNEL_OPTIONS=--iface=eth1' environment variable (because eth1 is my default not eth0) to /run/flannel/subnet.env and it worked

Comment: According to the [docs on environment variables](https://github.com/coreos/flannel/blob/master/Documentation/configuration.md#environment-variables), it looks like you could just set `FLANNELD_IFACE` too.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I've the same problem, trying to use k8s and Vagrant.
I've found this note in the [documentation of flannel](https://github.com/coreos/flannel/blob/master/Documentation/troubleshooting.md#vagrant):

> Vagrant typically assigns two interfaces to all VMs. The first, for
>   which all hosts are assigned the IP address 10.0.2.15, is for external
>   traffic that gets NATed.
>
> This may lead to problems with flannel. By default, flannel selects
>   the first interface on a host. This leads to all hosts thinking they
>   have the same public IP address. To prevent this issue, pass the
>   --iface eth1 flag to flannel so that the second interface is chosen.

So I look for it in the flannel's pod configuration.
If you download the [kube-flannel.yml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml) file, you should look at DaemonSet spec, specifically at the "kube-flannel" container. There, you should add the required "--iface=enp0s8" argument (Don't forget the "="). Part of the code I've used.

```
  containers:
  - name: kube-flannel
    image: quay.io/coreos/flannel:v0.10.0-amd64
    command:
    - /opt/bin/flanneld
    args:
    - --ip-masq
    - --kube-subnet-mgr
    - --iface=enp0s8
```

Then run `kubectl apply -f kube-flannel.yml`

Hope helps.

Comment: I was suspecting that the problem was around the iface flannel was using for the vxlan, but was trying to solve it changing the routing table. Your solution worked like a charm.

Comment: And also be sure to add the following to kubelet.service: `--node-ip={{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_enp0s8']['ipv4']['address'] }} `, this way the correct host IPs will be matching the Pod CIDRs

Comment: my iface is eth0

Comment: Hey lalo, your solution will work only if all nodes are the same! If the interface on some of the nodes isn't enp0s8 this won't work.

Comment: --iface-regex=10\.0\.*\.* is the answer

Comment: @AlexG thank you sir for this wonderful hint! This was **EXACTLY** what I was looking for. In my case we were building a hybrid cluster and some nodes where in different subnet. The `iface-regex` idea works absolutely brilliant! :)

Answer (score 1):

don't know directly running  "kubectl apply -f kube-flannel.yml" does not work at my side, it still show using interface with name eth0.

after running `kubectl delete -f kube-flannel.yml` then `kubectl apply -f kube-flannel.yml`, it shows using the interface with eth1:

```
I1122 11:31:44.405982       1 main.go:488] Using interface with name eth1 and address 192.168.0.24
I1122 11:31:44.406153       1 main.go:505] Defaulting external address to interface address (192.168.0.24)
I1122 11:31:44.428414       1 kube.go:131] Waiting 10m0s for node controller to sync
I1122 11:31:44.428552       1 kube.go:294] Starting kube subnet manager
I1122 11:31:45.429349       1 kube.go:138] Node controller sync successful
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @Libo-zhu, we experienced exactly the same behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

Foremost, nothing on the documentation page you linked says `/etc/sysconfig`; that is a very old directory that isn't suitable for systemd nor the kubernetes DaemonSet you are actually using. In addition, unless you are volume mounting something as `/etc/sysconfig`, then even putting that content into a file on the host filesystem won't help you when you run flannel in a container.

I *think* the shortest path to success is to add the command-line flag into [the flanneld argument list](https://github.com/coreos/flannel/blob/a5b458be07860a4231258f2908ea511154e37dc5/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml#L126) which you can easily do via `kubectl --namespace=kube-system edit daemonset kube-flannel-ds`, update the `container:` declaration, then `kubectl --namespace=kube-system delete pod -l app=flannel`