# Kubernetes PODs not accessible within the cluster

Tags: kubernetes

I tried to install `Kubernetes` with `kubeadm` on 3 virtual machines with `Debian` OS on my laptop, one as master node and the other two as worker nodes. I did exactly as the tutorials on [kubernetes.io](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/) suggests. I initialized cluster with command `kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16` and joined the workers with corresponding `kube join` command. I installed `Flannel` as the network overlay with command `kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml`.

The repsonse of command `kubectl get nodes` looks fine:

```
NAME        STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION   INTERNAL-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE
k8smaster   Ready    master   20h   v1.18.3   192.168.1.100   <none>        Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)   4.19.0-9-amd64   docker://19.3.9
k8snode1    Ready    <none>   20h   v1.18.3   192.168.1.101   <none>        Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)   4.19.0-9-amd64   docker://19.3.9
k8snode2    Ready    <none>   20h   v1.18.3   192.168.1.102   <none>        Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)   4.19.0-9-amd64   docker://19.3.9
```

The response of command `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces` doesn't show any error:

```
NAMESPACE     NAME                                READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE    IP              NODE        NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
kube-system   coredns-66bff467f8-7hlnp             1/1     Running   9          20h    10.244.0.22     k8smaster   <none>           <none>
kube-system   coredns-66bff467f8-wmvx4             1/1     Running   11         20h    10.244.0.23     k8smaster   <none>           <none>
kube-system   etcd-k8smaster                      1/1     Running   11         20h    192.168.1.100   k8smaster   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-apiserver-k8smaster            1/1     Running   9          20h    192.168.1.100   k8smaster   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-k8smaster   1/1     Running   11         20h    192.168.1.100   k8smaster   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-amd64-9c5rr          1/1     Running   17         20h    192.168.1.102   k8snode2    <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-amd64-klw2p          1/1     Running   21         20h    192.168.1.101   k8snode1    <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-amd64-x7vm7          1/1     Running   11         20h    192.168.1.100   k8smaster   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-proxy-jdfzg                    1/1     Running   11         19h    192.168.1.101   k8snode1    <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-proxy-lcdvb                    1/1     Running   6          19h    192.168.1.102   k8snode2    <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-proxy-w6jmf                    1/1     Running   11         20h    192.168.1.100   k8smaster   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-scheduler-k8smaster            1/1     Running   10         20h    192.168.1.100   k8smaster   <none>           <none>
```

Then i tried to create a `POD` with command `kubectl apply -f podexample.yml` with following content:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: example 
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx 
    image: nginx
```

Command `kubectl get pods -o wide` shows that the `POD` is created on worker node1 and is in `Running` state.

```
NAME      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE    IP            NODE       NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
example   1/1     Running   0          135m   10.244.1.14   k8snode1   <none>           <none>
```

The thing is, when i try to connect to the pod with `curl -I 10.244.1.14` command i get the following response in master node:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.244.1.14 port 80: Connection timed out
```

but the same command on the worker node1 responds successfully with:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.17.10
Date: Sat, 23 May 2020 19:45:05 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 612
Last-Modified: Tue, 14 Apr 2020 14:19:26 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "5e95c66e-264"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

I thought maybe that's because somehow `kube-proxy` is not running on master node but command `ps aux | grep kube-proxy` shows that it's running.

```
root     16747  0.0  1.6 140412 33024 ?        Ssl  13:18   0:04 /usr/local/bin/kube-proxy --config=/var/lib/kube-proxy/config.conf --hostname-override=k8smaster
```

Then i checked for kernel routing table with command `ip route` and it shows that packets destined for `10.244.1.0/244` get routed to flannel.

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp0s3 onlink 
10.244.0.0/24 dev cni0 proto kernel scope link src 10.244.0.1 
10.244.1.0/24 via 10.244.1.0 dev flannel.1 onlink 
10.244.2.0/24 via 10.244.2.0 dev flannel.1 onlink 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp0s3 scope link metric 1000 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp0s3 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.100
```

Everything looks fine to me and i don't know what else should i check to see what's the problem. Am i missing something?

UPDATE1:

If i start an `NGINX` container on worker node1 and map it's 80 port to port 80 of the worker node1 host, then i can connect to it via command `curl -I 192.168.1.101` from master node. Also, i didn't add any iptable rule and there is no firewall daemon like `UFW` installed on the machines. So, i think it's not a firewall issue.

UPDATE2:

I recreated the cluster and used `canal` instead of `flannel`, still no luck.

UPDATE3:

I took a look at canal and flannel logs with following commands and everything seems fine:

```
kubectl logs -n kube-system canal-c4wtk calico-node
kubectl logs -n kube-system canal-c4wtk kube-flannel
kubectl logs -n kube-system canal-b2fkh calico-node
kubectl logs -n kube-system canal-b2fkh kube-flannel
```

UPDATE4:

for the sake of completeness, [here are the logs of mentioned containers](https://gofile.io/d/rZIjLa).

UPDATE5:

I tried to install specific version of kubernetes components and docker, to check if there is an issue related to versioning mismatch with following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install docker-ce=18.06.1~ce~3-0~debian
sudo apt-get install -y kubelet=1.12.2-00 kubeadm=1.12.2-00 kubectl=1.12.2-00 kubernetes-cni=0.6.0-00
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/bc79dd1505b0c8681ece4de4c0d86c5cd2643275/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml
```

but nothing changed.

i even updated file `/etc/bash.bashrc` on all nodes to clear any proxy settings just to make sure it's not about proxy:

```
export HTTP_PROXY=
export http_proxy=
export NO_PROXY=127.0.0.0/8,192.168.0.0/16,172.0.0.0/8,10.0.0.0/8
```

and also added following environments to docker systemd file `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` on all nodes:

```
Environment="HTTP_PROXY="
Environment="NO_PROXY="
```

Then rebooted all nodes and when i logged in, still got `curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.244.1.12 port 80: Connection timed out`

UPDATE6:

i event tried to setup the cluster in `CentOS` machines. thought maybe there is something related to `Debian`. i also stopped and disabled `firewalld` to make sure that firewall is not causing problem, but i got the exact same result again: `Failed to connect to 10.244.1.2 port 80: Connection timed out`.

The only thing that now i'm suspicious about is that maybe it's all because of `VirtualBox` and virtual machines network configuration? The virtual machines are attched to a `Bridge Adapter` connected to my Wireless network interface.

UPDATE7:

I went inside the created POD and figured out there is no internet connectivity inside the POD. So, I created another POD from a `NGINX` image that has commands like `curl`, `wget`, `ping` and `traceroute` and tried `curl https://www.google.com -I` and got result: `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: www.google.com`. I checked `/etc/resolv.conf` file and found that the DNS server address inside the POD is `10.96.0.10`. Changed the DNS to `8.8.8.8` still `curl https://www.google.com -I` results in `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: www.google.com`. Tried to ping `8.8.8.8` and the result is `56 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 365ms`. For the last step i tried `traceroute 8.8.8.8` and got the following result:

```
 1  10.244.1.1 (10.244.1.1)  0.116 ms  0.056 ms  0.052 ms
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

I don't know the fact that there is no internet connectivity in POD has anything to do with the problem that i can't connect to POD within the cluster from nodes other than the one that POD is deployed on.

Comment: I remember having this issues like a year back, i fixed it by chaning it from flannel to canal, maybe try that

Comment: Check if there is a firewall on the worker nodes, and if they accept traffic from your node.

Comment: @BurakSerdar if i start an nginx container by docker on worker node1 and map port 80 of the worker node1 to port 80 of the created container, i can connect to the nginx on worker node1 from master node with `curl -I 192.168.1.101`. So, i think it's not about firewall. also i didn't set any firewall rule with `iptables` and there is no `UFW` installed on the machines.

Comment: can you reach a pod on one worker node from the other one?

Comment: @suren no, the pod is only accessible within worker node1. worker node2 get the same response as master node.

Comment: Where is it running? I mean on the cloud? You need to open up `ipip` protocol.

Comment: @suren machines are running on my laptop on `VirtualBox`

Comment: @paltaa i recreated the cluster with canal this time, no luck.

Comment: any information from the flannel or canal logs ?

Comment: @paltaa i don't know where canal logs are persisted. should i configure it in someway?

Comment: @paltaa i tried with `kubectl logs -n kube-system canal-b2fkh kube-flannel | grep ERROR` and `kubectl logs -n kube-system canal-b2fkh calico-node | grep ERROR` and `kubectl logs -n kube-system canal-c4wtk calico-node | grep ERROR` and `kubectl logs -n kube-system canal-b2fkh kube-flannel | grep ERROR` and found nothing.

Comment: how are you spinning up the cluster ? maybe dont grep and just post the logs and lets see whats happening, its clear that is a network problem

Comment: @paltaa i uploaded the log files and updated the answer. as i said, there is nothing suspicious in logs.

Comment: Which cri are you using, docker or containerd?

Comment: @Elgarni its `Docker`

Comment: Try `kubectl restart docker` on all nodes (starting from master).

Comment: If that does not work, try to watch the logs of kube proxy on the node a pod is running on, and then do any curl inside the pod, and share the logs outputted by the kube proxy

Comment: @Elgarni `kubectl restart docker` results with `Error: unknown command "restart" for "kubectl"`. i tried to execute `curl` inside the pod but it wasn't installed in `nginx` image. i tried to use `wget` it wasn't installed neither. tried to install it with `apt-get` figured out that POD can't connect to the internet.

Comment: My bad. I meant `systemctl`, restarting the service

Comment: @Elgarni tnx for your comment. i went inside the pod and explored a little bit. and i found that seems like i have DNS issues.

Comment: I have experienced exact same behavior with my kubeadm cluster on gcp with calico CNI. What solved my issue is to set the iptables to legacy (sometimes suggested for Debian): 
`sudo update-alternatives --set iptables /usr/sbin/iptables-legacy` and 
`sudo update-alternatives --set ip6tables /usr/sbin/ip6tables-legacy`. After that I deployed again calico and rebooted the all servers.I still don`t know why this fixed the the issue. Can you try and test this? Meanwhile I will try to reproduce this error in virtualbox.

Comment: While debugging I have traced the packets arrived at another server but somehow did not go through to the pod. I suspect is that CNI is picking up the wrong interface.  [This case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47845739/configuring-flannel-to-use-a-non-default-interface-in-kubernetes) explains that flannel picks the first interface on a host. Can you check and verify which interface flannel is using or perhaps point him the right one as suggested in the topic.

Comment: @acid_fuji OMG, this command `sudo update-alternatives --set iptables /usr/sbin/iptables-legacy` solved the issue. thanks man. please post an answer and i'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debian system uses `nftables` for the `iptables` backend which is not compatible with Kubernetes network setup. So you have to set it to use iptables-legacy instead of nftables with the following commands:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set iptables /usr/sbin/iptables-legacy 
sudo update-alternatives --set ip6tables /usr/sbin/ip6tables-legacy
```

Comment: seems like there are two sets of modules for packet filtering in kernel: `ip_tables`, and `nf_tables`. until recently `iptables` were using `ip_tables` module, but in `iptables 1.8`  they have deprecated `ip_tables` and using `nf_tables` under the hood. this problem arises when somehow `iptables 1.6` and `iptables 1.8` get invoked on the same host.