# It has different defaultgateway between masters and workers

Tags: kubernetes, overlay, calico

I have installed K8s cluster with master1 and worker1
They has each different default gateway.
It could communicate between pods on same node.
It couldn't communicate between pods on master and pods on worker.
I configured calico overlay between nodes for communication.
Could you know how to communicate between pods on master and pods on worker?

master gateway: 10.41.2.1
worker gateway: 10.41.84.1

Comment: How did you installed your k8s cluster? Kubeadm? You can ping from one node to other? All necessary ports are open in the firewall you have between them? [Check required ports](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/#check-required-ports).

Comment: I had installed k8s with kubeadm. It can ping between master and worker. It cat connect communication with port of default k8s you provide above. It seems to be a problem with calico overlay because other default gateway. when I ping with tun0 IP on master, It couldn't ping with tun0 on worker. Could you know how to route between master and worker ?

Comment: Are you using Debian? If yes, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62031947/12153576).

Comment: I am using the CentOS 7

Comment: Did you already solved this problem? What else have you tried?